# Convert WEP key to passphrase

Tags: wep, passphrase

How can I convert a 10-digit (in HEX) WEP key to it's corresponding passphrase? I've recovered the WEP key by a software tool (eg: 3666386162). Now I want to connect to this wifi network, so I need it's passphrase

#### The Question:

Is there any algorithms or tools or somethings else that can convert a WEP key to passphrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this page](http://www.dirtymonday.net/key_convert.html) or [this one](http://www.einhorn-net.de/jstools/wepkey.html)?

It converts the WEP Hex Key to a WEP Ascii key.

Otherwise you could do it manually according to the table below:

Your example Hex:`3666386162` = `36 66 38 61 62` translates to Ascii:`6f8ab`.

```
A   41  B   42  C   43  D   44  E   45  F   46  G   47  H   48
I   49  J   4A  K   4B  L   4C  M   4D  N   4E  O   4F  P   5O
Q   51  R   52  S   53  T   54  U   55  V   56  W   57  X   58
Y   59  Z   60  a   61  b   62  c   63  d   64  e   65  f   66
g   67  h   68  i   69  j   6A  k   6B  l   6C  m   6D  n   6E
o   6F  p   70  q   71  r   72  s   73  t   74  u   75  v   76
w   77  x   78  y   79  z   7A  0   30  1   31  2   32  3   33
4   34  5   35  6   36  7   37  8   38  9   39
```

**Edit:**

However, passphrases to HEX WEP keys are a **one way encryption**.
You **can't** get a passphrase from a HEX key.
(basically the 64-bit generator uses XOR's and PRNG to generate 4 keys. 104 bit uses MD5.)

[Here](https://gitorious.org/qt-wep-key-generator/pages/Home) is some more information about the key generation.
You can also read about how the HEX keys are generated from page 18 forward in [this document](http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~pld/courses/449/fall08/WEP_password_cracker.pdf).

Because there is **no way back** to the passphrase from a HEX key, there are 2 things you can do:

1. Change the keys in your router (assuming you have control over it).
   BTW If you have control over the router and it supports WPA or WPA2 it is advised to go with that.
2. Use the HEX key in your connection dialog. Often you can just enter the HEX key.
   Sometimes (Apple?) you need to put a `$` before it.

Comment: Nope, WEP key (in either HEX format or ASCII format) is different from passphrase. WEP key is a sequence of bits that can be used to encrypt the data, but passphrase is a word or phrase which is needed for authentication (password for WiFi network)

Comment: I added some more information about passphrases in my answer (see Edit).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested if these keys works yet, but it seems, that 40-bit keys can be generated by nwepgen from package linux-wlan-ng (Debian Jessie).